# Enable tls1.2 on windows 7 with powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell, windows-7, tls1.2

Cannot enable TLS1.2 on Windows 7SP1 with powershell 2.0 :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.8806
BuildVersion                   6.1.7601.17514
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

I guess P.Sv2.0 is using .NET v2.0 :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $PSVersionTable.CLRVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      50727  8806

PS C:\Windows\system32> [System.Environment]::Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      50727  8806
```

Moreover, the following .NET versions are installed on this system :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -Name Version, Release -ErrorAction 0 | where { $_.PSChildName -match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | select Version, Release, PSChildName

Version                           Release                          PSChildName
-------                           -------                          -----------
2.0.50727.5420                                                     v2.0.50727
3.0.30729.5420                                                     v3.0
3.0.4506.5420                                                      Windows Communication Foundation
3.0.6920.5011                                                      Windows Presentation Foundation
3.5.30729.5420                                                     v3.5
4.8.03761                         528049                           Client
4.8.03761                         528049                           Full
4.0.0.0                                                            Client
```

However, I cannot set TLSv1.2 with that configuration :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Exception lors de la définition de « SecurityProtocol » : « Impossible de convertir la valeur Null en type « System.Net.SecurityProtocolType » en raison de valeurs d'énumération non valides. Spécifiez l'une des valeurs d'énumération suivantes et réessayez. Les valeurs d'énumération possibles sont « Ssl3, Tls ». »
Au niveau de ligne : 1 Caractère : 28
+ [Net.ServicePointManager]:: <<<< SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
PS C:\Windows\system32> [enum]::GetNames([Net.SecurityProtocolType])
Ssl3
Tls
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

EDIT 0 : @mclayton Setting up `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol` to the integer value of `3072` does not work either :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 3072
Exception lors de la définition de « SecurityProtocol » : « Impossible de convertir la valeur « 3072 » en type « System.Net.SecurityProtocolType » en raison de valeurs d'énumérati
on non valides. Spécifiez l'une des valeurs d'énumération suivantes et réessayez. Les valeurs d'énumération possibles sont « Ssl3, Tls ». »
Au niveau de ligne : 1 Caractère : 28
+ [Net.ServicePointManager]:: <<<< SecurityProtocol = 3072
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: try `$Protocol = [Enum]::ToObject([System.Net.SecurityProtocolType], 3072);
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $Protocol`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Sorry for my late response, I don't have access to this computer everyday. Setting up  `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol` to the integer value of `3072` does not work either. Please see my EDIT 0.

Comment: Please use the full code, copy and paste if you have to. Why not just upgrade .net?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Your powershell snippet worked ! Thanks a lot. BTW : .NET v4.0 was already installed but powershell v2.0 is only using .NET v2.0. I guess I need to upgrade powershell upto powershell v3.0 (at least) be able to use .NET v >= 4.0. Can you please convert [your first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67740700/enable-tls1-2-on-windows-7-with-powershell-2-0#comment119735663_67740700) to an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @Abraham Zinala's comment, the `Tls12` enumeration value wasn't added to the `System.Net.SecurityProtocolType` enum until Dot Net Framework version 4.5 (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.securityprotocoltype?view=netframework-4.5).

Your PowerShell 2.0 install is using a lower version than this, so it can't resolve the value of `[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`.

What you can do instead is use the integer value of the enum:

```
# assign the magic number to a variable for clarity
$tls12 = 3072;

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $tls12;
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I don't have access to this computer everyday. Setting up  `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol` to the integer value of `3072` does not work either. Please see my EDIT 0.

Comment: Do I need to upgrade to powershell 3 to be able to use .NET v4 ?

Comment: I've upgraded to PS3.0. Your solution works with PS3.0/.NET4.0